# Cannot see response get request laravel phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, routes, phpunit

Excuses if this might be a duplicate, but I am not sure how to achieve the following. I am using phpunit to do some tests on routes in laravel and I am not able to receive any debugging information on why the route failed.

This is the code I am trying to test which simply calls some named routes:

```
foreach($companyNames as $companyName){
    $response = $this->call('GET', Config::get('app.url') . '/provider/' . $companyName);
    $response->assertStatus(200);
  }
```

The response I get from this when the assertStatus fails is:

> 1) Tests\Unit\ProviderPageRouteTest::testProviderPageRoutes
>
> Expected status code 200 but received 404.
>
> Failed asserting that false is true.

But what I want to see now is what route exactly failed so I can investigate the reason for the failed route. How can I receive this information from the response or request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the assertion, `dd` or `log` the following:

```
$response->exception->getStackTrace();
```

You can access any other exception message for the given class as well.

Comment: With this code I get this error message: 
Error: Call to a member function getStackTrace() on null

Comment: Ah yes because Laravel is converting 404 to a response in the exception handler. within ExceptionHandler.php add a line to print the exception at the top of this function `public function report(Exception $exception): void`